# How do I know the current swipe speed

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following simple code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  late Offset offsetAll =  const Offset(0,0);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (t){
            offsetAll+=t.delta;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: offsetAll,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
)
```

the previous code is for animate the widget depending on user finger . and it is work perfectly

my question is how could i know the current swipe speed that user's finger doing it

for example if the user swipe slow .. fast .. etc ...

i need to use that speed value later ...  to the following

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(.....HERE....), () {
  
 });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `onPanEnd` callback passes `DragEndDetails`with an ending velocity

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragEndDetails-class.html) subclass of `GestureDetector` class might help your case. It allows to access primary velocity of Horizontal drag. like this,

```
GestureDetector(
onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragEndDetails) {
     double t = dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity;
    },
),
```